# ATOM/apm: can't find module "npm"

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, atom-editor

In Windows 10:

```
  C:\Users\broven>apm

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Program Files (x86)\atom\app-1.8.0\resources\app\apm\lib\apm-cli.js:12:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Program Files (x86)\atom\app-1.8.0\resources\app\apm\lib\apm-cli.js:237:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Error tell me that i don't have npm , but I insatll it,and up to date.
what's the problem?

```
C:\Users\broven>npm

Usage: npm <command>   
npm@2.15.8 D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Comment: ?. Your npm is hella old, even for when you posted this. Check again bro.